# How to shortcut the "release/focus priority" on the FujiFilm X-T4?

Tags: camera-settings, fujifilm

I just bought a FujiFilm X-T4, and since it's my first FujiFilm camera I'm still lost in the menus. I found the option where I can set if I want it to focus before shooting or shoot right away: It's called RELEASE/FOCUS PRIORITY and can be found in the [AF/MF menu](http://fujifilm-dsc.com/en/manual/x-t3/menu_shooting/af_mf_setting/index.html).

Now how can I use a shortcut to quickly change it? I'm used to shoot a Nikon camera where I've set up a shortcut to toggle this option when a "fn" button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want a button that toggles between release and focus priority. As far as I can tell, this is *not* currently posslble.

What you can do:

- Add "Release/Focus Priority" to "My Menu". This will make it a little easier to find and change.
- Set AF-S to Focus Priority and AF-C to Release Priority, or vice versa. The AF mode becomes a proxy for switching release priority.

Note:

- It appears to also be *not* possible to add Release/Focus Priority to the Q menu.